# Timer function stops after some time automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

The timer function fires properly for an hour, after some time it stops automatocally
This is my code for timer declaration.

```
    private static System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    private static void SetTimer()
            {
                try
                {
                    myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
                    myTimer.Elapsed += Timer1_Tick;
                    myTimer.AutoReset = true;
                    myTimer.Enabled = true;
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Manager mgr = new Manager();
                    mgr.updateApplicationError(e.Message, "Timer Stopped");
                }
            }
```

This is the code for the Function that called on Timer tick

```
 public static void Timer1_Tick(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Minute % 15 == 2)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SendMessage();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        updateApplicationError("App Load - " + ex.Message, "SAP -> STS interface error");    
                    }        
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("***NOT TICK***"+ DateTime.Now.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: try declare your timer in a field: `private static Timer _timer;` and then in method `SetTimer` set your `_timer`. I've seen similar question somewhere, can't find

Comment: @Potato it's already a field

Comment: @Prem The Timer doesn't stop firing as long as it exists. Which means it no longer exists after a while. Unless the class where `SetTimer` is used is a singleton, the timer will be garbage-collected when its object gets GC'd too. In *all* ASP.NET web stacks, the objects created to server a request live only as long as that request and get GC'd afterwards

Comment: @Prem what are you trying to do? You can't create a long-running timer, or any background service in ASP.NET by creating a timer in a controller or firing off a Task or Thread. Even it the thread isn't GC'd the objects it depends on may be GC'd. Check Scott Hanselman's [How to Run Background tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-run-background-tasks-in-aspnet)

Comment: @Potato already declared as  private static. Updated in the question.

Comment: In ASP.NET Core you can use a BackgroundService class. Check [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). The examples show how to create a timed and a queued service. You don't need to create a separate worker service project either, just add `AddHostedService` in your `Startup.cs`

Comment: @Prem doesn't matter. Doesn't work this way. Are you using .NET Old or .NET Core? The easiest way to create a timed service in .NET Core is the BackgroundService. Or use eg Hangfire or Coravel, for a full-featured job scheduler

Comment: @Prem the timer may be static but the classes used by the event handler probably aren't. Even the logging calls may fail because `updateApplicationError` is trying to use disposed objects

Comment: BTW if you need to send email messages periodically, [Coravel](https://github.com/jamesmh/coravel) is probably the best choice. It's a scheduler with built-in mailer functionality

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No I need to make GRPC request to a java server

Comment: You still can't use a timer in a static field.